# In PHP classes, what is the equivalent of self from python classes?

Tags: php, python, class, self

In PHP, how can I achieve something like this from Python?

```
class CrowdProcess():
    def __init__(self,variable):
        self.variable = variable

    def otherfunc(self):
        print self.variable
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP uses `$this` as a reference to the instance:

```
class CrowdProcess
{
    public $variable;

    public function __construct($variable)
    {
        $this->variable = $variable;
    }

    public function otherfunc()
    {
        echo $this->variable, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

For more information, see http://php.net/language.oop5.basic#example-155

Comment: Can I then make a call like $CP = new CrowdProcess('defining the variable'); and expect that the $this->variable inside the construct becomes 'defining the variable' ?

Comment: No need to answer, I tried it and it does :) Thanks for the "translation" !

Comment: I went ahead added a link that you might find useful.  Happy PHP'ing (:

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$this->variable` in PHP :)